# What effect does Agriculturist have?

Tags: stardew-valley

The text of the profession says

> All crops grow 10% faster

How does that actually translate into gameplay?

(please avoid spoilers if possible)

---

To clarify the question, crops grow in a small, *whole number* of days, the actual effect cannot be anything approximating being 10% faster.

For crops that only yield one harvest per seed, the effect is going to have to be either:

- Some crops are unaffected, and some are shortened by one day
- Some crops are shortened by one day, and some are shortened by two days

Which is it? How do I know ahead of time which crops are which?

For crops that yield multiple harvests, is there an additional possibility that the time between harvests is irregular?

Comment: Remark: google searches only seem to turn up numbers for how things worked a year ago, but (AFAIK) this has been changed by patch.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe this was changed? I can't find anything that would suggest it was on the wiki.

Comment: @Studoku: I saw a lot of references to it being fixed in a patch; presumably [patch 1.07](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/4ddlr8/stardew_valley_patch_107/) since it's listed as a bugfix in the patch notes. Also, everything I found discussing the profession was dated 2016.

Comment: @Studoku: Also, I don't see anything on the official wiki that answers my question anyways.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at the decompiled code of the game, the profession works just like fertilizers. The whole number of days is reduced by 10% then rounded down, which mean the reduction will always be **at least one day**.

For multi-harvest crops, the time between the harvest is not affected. Only the initial grow time (before the first harvest) is reduced.

Each single crop will be affected individually, which mean they will all receive the exact same reduction and will all be available for harvest the same day. For multi-harvest crops will have regular harvest.

This mean that cauliflowers will grow in 10 days, and parsnips in only 3 days!

---

Relevant code is available [here](https://github.com/AdamMcIntosh/StawdewValley/blob/master/TerrainFeatures/HoeDirt.cs). Look at lines 234 to 240, tho it might be hard to understand as the decompiler does not preserve variables name.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't the code specifically say `Math.Ceiling`? Rounding down _could_ produce a 0 value, right?

Comment: @IvoCoumans In the code, the `Math.Ceiling` is not applied to the number of days reduced by 10%, but to the number of days to remove (calculated by multiplying the normal growth time by the percentage of days to remove). The number of days to remove is finally subtracted to the normal growth time.  

It may be confusing as my explanations do not exactly match the code, but in the end, the resulting growth time is the same. I tried to reduce the number of operations so it is easier to explain and understand.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it translates into gameplay like this: For example the Cauliflower takes 12 days until harvest. 10% of 12 is 1.2, so with the agricultrist profession, the 12 days it takes to harvest Cauliflower end up being 10.8 days (which is rounded up to 11 days). I don't think it has anything to do with the number of crops being planted or some plants being affected by it while others are not.